# how to round decimal values to number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update decimal values using  **CAST FUNCTION**

**Example values:**

[image: Discount_Value]

**Result like this:**

[image: Discount_Result]

Comment: Please add a question to your post. "I want" is not a question, nor does it show any research or effort on your part. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 5):

That type of formatting should probably be done in your application layer rather than in SQL Server.

You would use the column name `discount_perc` instead of `0.4` in the following examples:

---

You can use `cast()` like so:

```
select cast(cast(0.4*100 as int) as varchar(12))+'%'
```

returns: `40%`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PSPVY57957

---

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
select format(0.4,'0%')
```

returns: `40%`

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)